# How do you put a JButton at a x, y position

Tags: java, swing, layout, jbutton

I want a JButton at a x, y position and I have no clue on how to do that so I figured that I would ask here.
I can't get the buttons in the right place at all so I want to place them after the x, y system.

Comment: It's pretty uncommon to require to position precisely at a pixel position. Usually, you want relative positionning (I want this button after that textfield, I want that label 10 pixels below that image, etc...). Take a look into the various LayoutManager's available and possibly use several of them with nested panels to achieve the desired layout.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a `JPanel` and a layout manager

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) is a visual guide on what layout managers do

I think that `gridLayout` is the easiest to get results from in your case.  Just make a `JPanel`, add a `gridLayout` as its layout manager, and then add your `JButton` to the `JPanel`

Here is how you setup a `gridLayout`

```
int rows = 8;
int cols = 3;
GridLayout myLayout = new GridLayout(rows,cols);
myPanel = new JPanel();
myPanel.setLayout(myLayout);
myPanel.add(myButton);
```

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html) is some more detail on gridlayouts

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tutorial for null Layout Manager. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html

Basically, you need

```
    frame.setLayout(null);
    JButton b1 = new JButton("one");
    frame.add(b1);
    b1.setBounds(left, top, width, height);
```

Comment: Never use `null` layout. Bad advice always leading to code hard to maintain.

Comment: @GuillaumePolet I agree null layout is bad most of the time. But this is what the question explicitly asked for. And there are use cases where null layout is appropriate. The best voted GridLayout solution doesn't solve the problem OP is facing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `jpanel` you need to set `jpanel1.setLayout(new GridLayout(rows,columns))`, then just add your buttons with `jpanel1.add(YourButton)`.

Other option is to use `jbutton1.setBounds(posX,posY, width, height)`.

Comment: `jbutton1.setBounds` will not work with LayoutManager's. And you should always use a LayoutManager, no matter what.